# I want to add shaders to minecraft for windows 10 but can't access files

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to add some shaders but when i run %appdata% there are no minecraft files. I can't even find where it is downloaded onto my computer. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Most (if not all) shaders are built for java edition. Which shader are you looking to install?

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you where are Minecraft files not how to install shaders.

1. Windows-SSD (C-drive)
2. Users
3. Your Name
4. Go to `view` and check `Hidden items` on the right.
5. You will see `app data`. open it.
6. Local
7. Packages
8. Microsoft.Minecraft and a string of numbers and letters
9. LocalState
10. Games
11. com.mojang
12. Done!

C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 it is impossible to add shaders on Minecraft

Comment: Any source supporting your statement?

Comment: @pinckerman no I don't

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some shaders for Minecraft bedrock edition that can be downloaded as .mcaddons. You can just double-click on the file to run it.
Alternatively, if you have an RTX graphics card, you can use the built-in ray-tracing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).